# Problem with compiling python with matplotlib and cv

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, libraries

I am new to python and I am learning computer vision with it. I have a small problem in compiling my program.

I made sure both libraries are installed

here is the code that causes the problem:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2


#%matplotlib qt


image = mpimg.imread('car.jpg')
print("image dimenesions:", image.shape)
```

when I compile using python3.6, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "images.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

but when I compile with python alone, I get an error earlier in the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "images.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I am guessing that libraries are installed in different directories for different versions of python, How can I solve this problem?

If you think this might be caused by something else, What is it?

Comment: `cv2` module, i.e. OpenCV, does not come included in python. How did you install `cv2`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I used this command sudo python3.6 -m pip install opencv-python

Comment: Try remove any existing installations in `site-packages` and try again